# Unique identifier for In App Purchase

Tags: android, memory, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app with In App Purchase which it is currently a purely client side app. However since this purchase are permanent I need to store this in the device somewhere (unless their is a better option as currently there is no need for a user to use online services)

For this to work i need to get some type of unique identifier when a user successful purchase the product, does play service have such functionality?.

I'm sure this is not possible but is there any type of storage location that can not be accessed by root user with an exception for advanced user with kernel knowledge. SharedPreference currently what I'm using but this is high level access, any way to use c++ to store in physical memory but no file mapping (access though physical memory address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `orderId` which is basically used as a unique order identifier for the transaction in [`getBuyIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent) method. This identifier corresponds to the Google payments order ID. If the order is a test purchase made through the In-app Billing Sandbox, `orderId` is blank.

See [purchasing an item](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Purchase) in [Implementing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#purchase) for more information.